# Asynchronous Geoserver WPS Example

Tags: geoserver, wps

Anyone have a Java based example of how to implement an asynchronous Geoserver web processing service (WPS)? Based on some presentations that I found, async GeoServer WPS support was added in 2.1.3. I've searched the internet and also the GeoServer and GeoTools websites with no luck.

My environment = PostgreSQL 9.2.7 + PostGIS + GeoServer 2.4.5 + JDK 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
this is part of the protocol not part of the specific process.

Once you expose a process via WPS in GeoServer you can ask for the asynchronous execution as per the standard WPS protocol.

Simone.

Comment: I'm looking at the xsd for wps and don't see how to make the request asynchronous. I'm looking at http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsExecute_request.xsd

Comment: this old discussion might get you started: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/WPS-getting-asynchronous-execution-td3820072.html

Comment: I know you're trying to help me, but a developer discussion is a bit cryptic and difficult to understand. Do I just add storeResponse=true and status=true to the request URL. If so how? Thanks for your help, I don't mean to complain.

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141223/execute-geoserver-wps-asynchronously it needed to be storeExectureResponse