# Execute GeoServer WPS asynchronously

Tags: geoserver, wps

I want to execute GeoServer WPS process asynchronously.
Is it necessary to change anything inside a synchronous process or to customize specific parameters at execution? I've tried to add mode="async" into wps request parameters, but geoserver wrote:

> Attribute 'mode' is not allowed to appear in element 'wps:Execute'.

Is there any examples of the asynchronous process realisation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution and may be it will help someone ...

For asynchronous request you need to add this attributes:

> storeExecuteResponse=true status=true

GET request example:

> http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=execute&identifier=gs:Test&DataInputs=testParam%3dtest&storeExecuteResponse=true&status=true

POST request example:

`<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1">
  <ows:Identifier>gs:Test</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>testParam</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>test</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:ResponseDocument storeExecuteResponse="true" status="true">
      <wps:Output>
        <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title>result</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>result</ows:Abstract>
      </wps:Output>
    </wps:ResponseDocument>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>`