# Missing zoom levels in MBTiles generated from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, android, mbtiles

I have added **MBTiles** plugin to my GeoServer in order to generate my maps in .mbtiles format, so I can read maps in offline mode.

My problem is that, when I preview my maps in GeoServer, it includes all zoom levels, but once I downloaded .mbtile file I found that it contains only zoom levels from 1 to 5. And when I changed the `EPSG:4326` to `EPSG:3857` it doesn't work but when I opened the .mbtiles file from dbBrowser for SQLite 3 I found that it contains another range of zoom levels: this time from 19 to 21.

The request is:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=mdintimaps:test&styles=&srs=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=-76.962,-76.735,120.066,69.01&width=768&height=568&format=mbtiles

Any help?

Comment: Please specify how you are generating the MBTiles file

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm generating my mbtiles using this url: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=mdintimaps:test&styles=&srs=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=-76.962,-76.735,120.066,69.01&width=768&height=568&format=mbtiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mbtiles/output.html) you should specify the min and max zoom levels desired, otherwise the output format will make a best guess as to which zoom levels to return in order to respond quickly (a WMS request is synchronous).

However, if you want to generate many zoom levels, best to make a asynchronous WPS request instead, a WMS one will likely time out before it completes. You can use the WPS request demo builder to set up a rough template, and then modify it [to be asynchronous](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141223/execute-geoserver-wps-asynchronously)

Comment: I appreciate all of your help, i found the zoom levels in the documentation but i was doing it in the wrong way, i wasn't specifying the format_options parameter. I was specifying max_zoom directly in the url so the correct one should be this way: [http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Mylayer&styles=&bbox=-17.64404,-1.0,0.54932,36.90597&width=368&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format_options=min_zoom=0;max_zoom:30&format=mbtiles]    But the result of mbtiles is about 1gb.   Thank you so much for your help